# Replacing JSON Formatted String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a something like this in my table column:

```
{"InputDirection":0,"Mask":"AA","FormatString":null,"AutoCompleteValue":null,
 "Filtered":"0123456789","AutoComplete":false,"ReadOnly":true}
```

What I want to do is to change A to N in `"Mask":"AA"` and remove `"Filtered":"0123456789"` if they exist. Mask could be in different forms like `A9A`, 'AAAA`, etc.

If it was in C# I could do it by myself by parsing it to JSON, etc but I need to do it within SQL.

I've found this article which shows how to parse `JSON` to `Table`. This gave me an idea that I can parse each field to temp table and make the changes on that and convert it back to JSON so update the actual field where I take this JSON field from. However, this looks like a cumbersome process for both me and the server.

Any better ideas?

Comment: "this looks like a cumbersome process" --- that's what happens when you want to store structured data in hardly manageable form.

Comment: @zerkms: Don't tell me, this is how I found it like that.

Comment: Since you can do it in C#, why not write that and expose it as a SQL function?

Comment: @araqnid: What do you mean?

Comment: @Tarik you can write a method in C# (can be any CLR language) and link the assembly into SQL Server: I've done this for being able to gzip text into blobs, although it was a while back so I'm hazy on the details. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [LINK](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)  .

And then use the following code

```
select * into #demo from
(Select * from parseJSON('{"InputDirection":0,"Mask":"AA","FormatString":null,"AutoCompleteValue":null,
 "Filtered":"0123456789","AutoComplete":false,"ReadOnly":true}

')) a

select * from #demo

--- CHANGE THE DATA HERE AS REQUIRED


DECLARE @MyHierarchy JSONHierarchy;
INSERT INTO @myHierarchy
select * from #demo;


-- USE THIS VALUE AND UPDATE YOUR JSON COLUMN
SELECT dbo.ToJSON(@MyHierarchy)


drop table #demo
```

Comment: @Tarik : Does this help or I gave solution in wrong direction ?

Comment: This is really cool but the parseJSON function throws an error, "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." when it encounters on empty array in the hierarchy (for example: [ ]).

Answer (score 0):

I may be getting something wrong here but why can’t you simply use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to update what’s needed and LIKE to identify JSON strings that should be updated?

```
update table_T
set json_string = REPLACE(json_string, '"Filtered":"0123456789",', '')
where json_string like '%"Mask":"AA"%'
```

Not sure I understand why do you need to parse it….

Comment: We also need to change 'A' to 'N' only for Mask's value. Parsing it will allow any other change also easily.

Comment: Yes, we also need to change 'A' to 'N' my precioussss...!

Comment: [42883] ERROR: function replace(json, unknown, unknown) does not exist. No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. - PostgreSQL

Answer (score -1):

I finally found how to do it on postgresql:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = replace(column_name::TEXT, '"name:"', '"my-other-name:"')::json
WHERE id = 1;
```